# Is there a yardstick for detecting low quality answers?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, declined-flags, low-quality-posts, late-answers

A while ago, when I was reviewing, encountered this post and failed to correctly respond:

[A ***bad*** answer according to the review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/8627062)

The lesson that I understood from this review audit:

> I should flag those type of answers to be closed

In that case, I didn't, so I was suspended. Not a big deal.

Today I flagged [a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328994/invalid-gradle-jdk-configuration-found/31963044#31963044) as *Very Low Quality*. but a moderator has reviewed my flag and has not found an evidence to support it (Flag was declined).

I am really puzzled. Where am I wrong? What action is appropriate when facing such answers while reviewing?

Edit:

Another hassle: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/9146713) does not contain main part of the code that the user has tried so far. When reviewing it, I left a comment to tell him that posting just a link to your code is not sufficient and it is better to post main parts of your code. But it was an audit and I was failed. It tells me to leave it as it is or upvote it.

Comment: You are asking for two different things: 1. When to flag VLQ. 2. How to review late answers.

Comment: Downvotes are often more appropriate than flags.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I don't understand, the audit answer is now deleted, that means that is has been correctly flagged by others. But why my flag for the other answer was declined?

Comment: @Deduplicator I am asking what is the appropriate action for these answers?

Comment: A VLQ flag means: "This post is really bad and should be deleted now."  The answer you flagged as such is a legitimate answer.  If you feel it's too short or poorly explained, downvote it.  "_[specify the] path to portable (non installed) JDK8_" is an answer without any serious formatting or other problems.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Then shouldn't we judge that **use  PL/SQL to conver .dmp to .csv   ** is similarly an answer without any serious formatting or other problems?

Comment: That one actually does have formatting problems, espcially within the context of the First-Post queue.  But even then, a downvote is more appropriate than VLQ flag.  Yes, it's a bad answer.  So downvote it.

Comment: @ryanyuyu It is really hard for me to distinguish a fundamental deference between the two. Should I give up reviewing?

Comment: I'm not sure how this will help but here you go: http://cdn.dick-blick.com/items/557/06/55706-1036-3ww-l.jpg

Comment: @DaveS I thought that URL might be NSFW going by the domain name

Comment: yikes, didn't even realize that. Thankfully that domain is just an Art Supplier

Answer (score 2):

The answer does not deserve a VLQ flag. This one should be reserved for really bad posts requiring an immediate action - not appropriate here. As originally written, the post could have better been posted as a comment, so we should wonder whether it deserves a Not An Answer flag. Here again, I am not sure because it tries to answer the asked question. I would not flag it because it says I did that and it solved the problem - as such, it is an answer IMHO. But here we are clearly in the grey zone: some of us would say it is an answer (even if a poor one), some would say is is not.

That's the reason why, we have flags and votes for those close and delete reasons: many members must agree for the action to be taken.

So you failed an audit for being too laxist and saw your flag rejected for being too strict. My understanding on that is the same as for navy gunners: one short shot, one long shot, your are now near the target! Don't worry about that, many of us failed audits and had rejected flags.

Anyway, as you were told in comments, the post was clearly poor and deserved to be downvoted... Next time if unsure just do that.